# Doubt related to Linear Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Attaching Snapshot

> [image]
>
> [From `Section 1.5` of the book [Advanced Calculus for Applications
> By Francis B. Hildebrand](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/M9xfPQAACAAJ?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL14SUspn4AhUkgWMGHXuqA9sQ7_IDegQIFRAD)]

I am learning differential equations, but I am having difficulty in understanding what author is trying to convey in the section enclosed inside the blue bracket?

I know  $$\frac{\partial[ L{e}^{rx}]}{\partial r}=0  $$  at $r=r_1$ but I cannot follow how this leads to the conclusion for giving the solution?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you have really understood everything in the first $8$ pages then this explanation should be clear to you. I can't think of a way to explain it without using essentially the same argument. If you can point to the first particular sentence where you are stuck and say what you think it means perhaps we can help. Do that by editing the question, not in comments, and put the math in the question, not in an image. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for posting the link . This is  my first time asking a question on this site so  I did know how equations were written. It was a great help. I have also included the part where I got struck more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you differentiate the first expression in the blue box using the product rule and the chain rule the result  will still have $(x-r_1)$ as a factor because $(x-r_1)$ occurs in the original with an exponent greater than $1$.

Comment: I understand that part but I am having trouble following how this leads to the solution corresponding to the double root?

Comment: It works that way because of what happens when you differentiate $xe^{x}$. Just check that the last line really does give solutions to the homegeneous equation whatever the values of the constants.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand now. Thank you for your attention.